# Authentication with android app in a django server

Tags: android, json, django, authentication, curl

I have created a server with help of django-restframework and django admin. Its a simple  server that response a request, with a list of musics in json format.
When i enter in the site `http://127.0.0.1/music/` it shows link for an authentication page. After authentication i can see all the content, and post a music or get a list of musics.
From my terminal(ubuntu), i can post some content by using the comand `"curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/ -d "code=print 789" -u user:password"`.
However  i'm very newbie and have no ideia how can i do that from my android app.
I have seen a lot of examples about how consuming webservice, like [this one](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/), but no one shows how can i make authentication.
Sorry if this is a trivial question, i'm only working in that project for a few days and i haven't programming knowledge.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

I created an api-token-auth using [that tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication). Then i did a POST by these codes:

```
public class ServiceHandler {

private static final String targetURL = "host/api-token-auth/";

public static String executePost(){
    UsuarioSenha usuariosenha;
    usuariosenha = new UsuarioSenha();
    usuariosenha.username="myusername";
    usuariosenha.password="mypassword";
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    Gson gson= new Gson();
    String user_pass_json = gson.toJson(usuariosenha);


    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = null;
    try{
        //Criando a conexão
        URL tagetUrl = new URL(targetURL);
        httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) tagetUrl.openConnection();

        httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpConnection.connect();


        //Enviando Request
        OutputStream outputStream = httpConnection.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(user_pass_json.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();

        if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() != 200){
            return ("Failed : HTTP error code : " + httpConnection.getResponseCode());
        }

        //Recebendo Response
        InputStream is = httpConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line;
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "MalformedURLException";

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ""+httpConnection.getErrorStream ();
    }finally {

        if(httpConnection != null) {
            httpConnection.disconnect(); 
        }
    }
}
}
```

So, i get return the string

> { 'token' : '9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b' }

just like the [Django Rest Framework site](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)g shows.

Thank you all, Especially Martol1ni!

Answer (score 0):

I would look into https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt which gives you an authentication token, then you can simply send post requests from your android app and include the username and password.

Comment: Ok, I have implemented the api-token-auth through the URI  http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/, just like you showed me. My problem now its how to use the HttpURLConnection by java.net (i think that's the right one) on my android app.
I have my class UserPass {
    String user
    String password
}
So I use Gson to convert a UserPass object on to a Json String.
How can i post that Json String to recover the token from the /api-token-auth/?