# How to use django authentication(django.contrib.auth) with my Android app

Tags: android, django, django-authentication

I am using Django as my backend for my android app. I have been handling post request using @csrf-exempt annotation with my views as I wasn't able to deal with csrf verification while sending post request from android(VOLLEY LIBRARY).
Now, I have to use django.contrib.auth login and logout methods but sessions aren't working when I am sending post request from android.

I had tried enabling cookies with my request in android but that also didn't work(enabling cookies also did not solve the csrf verification failed issue).Also I tried taking csrf token from a GET request to django( django.middleware.csrf - get_token) and then passing that csrf token in headers(X-CSRF-TOKEN)in my post requests, that also didn't work.

Code that I used to enable cookies in android:

```
CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();   
CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
```

So,
1. I don't know how to use django scripts without using @csrf-exempt from android.
2. and how to use django login with android

Answer (score 4):

Here is a generic response on using django as a backend: [Is it possible to develop the back-end of a native mobile app using the python powered framework Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760059/is-it-possible-to-develop-the-back-end-of-a-native-mobile-app-using-the-python-p)

More specifically this is normally done with a JWT - json web token: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#django-rest-auth
I'm sure other rest/ api frameworks exist but I normally use DRF.

Here is an example with a tutorial: [Authentication with android app in a django server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398065/authentication-with-android-app-in-a-django-server)

Comment: Actually, I am using same django backend of my website for android app and I have all my views written already for website and I have used django.contrib.auth for authentication. How can I use the same for my app(without django-rest method you suggested)? I have already listed the problem I am facing with this

Comment: Django rest framework just extends your existing app and exposes rest api endpoints and some helpful tools for remote authentication, so I am not proposing building a separate app.  But I think I understand what you are trying to do - and I'll bow out because I've never personally built an app in that way.  Best of luck! Hopefully somebody else has more experience in that.